# SQL Server Timecard Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a timecard table like below. The HourType field represents whether the Employee entered the time ("0"), or whether their supervisor overrides or enters time ("1"). If a supervisor overrides time there is both a 0 record and a 1 record (4/8/2019). If a supervisor enters time the employee did not, then there is only a 1 record (4/12/2019). I need a query to find the total time for a given week. So in the below example the total hours for this week should be 39.5 hours.

```
RecordId EmployeeId StartDate  EndDate   StartTime   EndTime      HourCount HourType
1        100        4/8/2019   4/8/2019  9:00:00 AM  5:00:00 PM   8         0
2        100        4/8/2019   4/8/2019  9:00:00 AM  4:30:00 PM   7.5       1
3        100        4/9/2019   4/9/2019  9:00:00 AM  5:00:00 PM   8         0
4        100        4/10/2019  4/10/2019 9:00:00 AM  5:00:00 PM   8         0
5        100        4/11/2019  4/11/2019 9:00:00 AM  5:00:00 PM   8         0
6        100        4/12/2019  4/12/2019 9:00:00 AM  5:00:00 PM   8         1
```

---

Added 2nd data set that would include multiple records per day to account for lunch hours (4/11/2019). Total Hours for this dataset should be 37.5.

```
RecordId EmployeeId StartDate  EndDate   StartTime   EndTime       HourCount HourType
1        100        4/8/2019   4/8/2019  9:00:00 AM  5:00:00 PM    8         0
2        100        4/8/2019   4/8/2019  9:00:00 AM  4:30:00 PM    7.5       1
3        100        4/9/2019   4/9/2019  9:00:00 AM  5:00:00 PM    8         0
4        100        4/10/2019  4/10/2019 9:00:00 AM  5:00:00 PM    8         0
5        100        4/11/2019  4/11/2019 9:00:00 AM  12:00:00 PM   3         0
6        100        4/11/2019  4/11/2019 9:30:00 AM  12:00:00 PM   2.5       1 
7        100        4/11/2019  4/11/2019 1:00:00 PM  5:00:00 PM    4         0   
8        100        4/12/2019  4/12/2019 9:00:00 AM  5:00:00 PM    8         1
```

Comment: The solution becomes difficult with that amendment.  For example, on the 4/11/2019 the employee entered two rows of data, and one row was overridden by the supervisor, but how can we determine which row has been overridden.  I think you will need another column containing the Record ID of the original row.

Comment: It could also be the case that the employee added a row for the morning, but the supervisor entered a row for the afternoon.  In which case the supervisor's row wouldn't be overriding the original, but would be an additional row, but there's no way to tell given the current table structure.

Comment: @paulH Yeah that is my dilemma. Unfortunately it is a 3rd party application so I can only use what they give me.

Comment: Does the application enforce any rules - for example, invalidating *every* row for a specific day for an employee if the supervisor overrides any entry?  There must be either some rules, or some additional information in the database (or the application is broken, which is always a possibility worth considering)

Comment: I think I may have found a solution using the LAG and LEAD functions. I'll be able to pull in the data from the previous and next rows and check for any supervisor overrides. I'll post a full solution once I am finished.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want:

```
select employeeId, sum(hourcount)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by employeeid, startdate, enddate order by hourtype desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

That is, if multiple records match `emplyeeid`, `startdate`, and `enddate`, then choose the override one.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I tried your query and found a flaw in my question. Can you take a look at my amended data set? What about if there are multiple records for one day when a person would clock out for lunch and clock back in.